# Conversion from float (native float or numpy.float64) to integer not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, integer

I have a dataframe thats loaded with floats and NaNs. I need to convert all the decimals/floats to integers. I checked that all types are numpy.float64 but my conversion to integer does not work. This is what the dataframe looks like.

[image]

Currently, I am using this code to attempt to change all non NaNs to integers, but it is not replacing the floats with integers in the dataframe.

```
for i, row in df_cn.iterrows():
    for col in df_cn.columns:
        cell = row[col]
        if isinstance(cell, np.float64) and np.isnan(cell) == False:
            cell = int(cell)
            df_cn.loc[i,col] = cell
```

This for loop does not replace the floats with ints and also I get this error even though I used df_cn.loc[]:

[image]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I did a similar process converting strings to datetime with similar logic and that worked out fine. Perhaps I am missing something very obvious. I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Do you even need to use `iterrows()` for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should change your datatype from float to int

```
for col in df_cn.columns:
    df_cn[col]=df_cn[col].astype(int)
```

You need to replace the nan's with an int (for example 0) before doing this
`df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

Here is a sample dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ "D": [1.0, np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7],"E": [np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)

D    int32
E    int32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only numbers in your dataframe you could try:

```
df_c = df.applymap(np.int64)
```

But if your dataframe could contain non-numeric values, this will leads to an error.

If you still prefer to use your own code, try this:

```
for i, row in df_cn.iterrows():
for col in df_cn.columns:
    cell = row[col]
    if isinstance(cell, np.float) and not np.isnan(cell):
        cell = int(cell)
        df_cn.loc[i,col] = cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas, by default, creates series of numbers as a float type if there are np.nan values: [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

> Because NaN is a float, a column of integers with even one missing values is cast to floating-point dtype (see Support for integer NA for more). Pandas provides a nullable integer array, which can be used by explicitly requesting the dtype

You would need to use these data types for a nullable integer provided in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-intna):

1. Int8Dtype
2. Int16Dtype
3. Int32Dtype
4. Int64Dtype